# Proposal for two new participation badges

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, badge-request, participation

There are two badges, Enthusiast and Fanatic, for frequent participation on SE sites. They require every-day participation including Saturdays, Sundays, and holidays. Maybe Fanatic should really be termed "Addict".

For the more sane part of the population (following typical working-day patterns, having a family life, following religious practice of regular holidays etc.) there are no such badges.

Here are my suggestions:

1. Silver badge "Workforce" Visit a SE site on 60 days during a 90 day period
2. Gold badge "Hero of Socialist Labour" Visit a SE site on 200 days during a one year period

What do you think?

P.S. Those badges aren't meant as replacement for the Fanatic type of badges, they are meant as additional badges with different requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SE development team has declined this suggestion, with the implied reason "We don't need those badges".

**[Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard) says:**

Personally I think it's an interesting idea, but the existing badges are enough and we don't need this "softened" version of them. Also, do note there is the [Yearling silver badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling) which does not require any consecutive days, just to be active on the site and earn 200 rep.

**[Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio) says:**

Even observant Jews who don't go online on Shabbat (for about 25 hours a week) [figured out how to earn Fanatic](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7594/472). It just takes a certain level of dedication... fanatical, you might say.